# How use like condition in mysql with more words

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-like

I have a filed in database in which there is a text  with a lot of words. In my front end i created a search box in which i would filter in many ways. I could write only one word or a lot of words and i should able to find the correct filed in which there are theese words. Actually i use the LIKE condition but this condition works only if i write one word or if the words are as written in the database with same order.. Is it possible do it even if the words i write are in "random order"? this is the example i use:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE description LIKE '%".$description."%' ";
```

Comment: explode `$description` at space and then chain each one together with ..`OR LIKE..`. Alternatively, replace space with pipe and use `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: this is the other way i tried but not works:   $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE description LIKE '%".implode('%', explode(' ', $description))."%' ";

Comment: You might find [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) useful.

Comment: and using implode solution?

Comment: Yes, @showdev is quite right. If you carry on down this route, you'll likely end up implementing MySQL's full text search, or something like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org) or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com), only not as well (not that I'm commenting on your skills, it's just that those projects have had many, many developers working on this problem for years.) Might be worth looking into using them from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explode and implode with OR condition for each words.

```
$descriptionArr = explode(" ", $description);
if(!is_null($descriptionArr)) {
   foreach($descriptionArr as $search) {
     $descriptionQuery[] = " description LIKE '%{$search}%' ";
   }
   $condition = " WHERE " . implode(" OR ", $descriptionQuery);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table {$condition}";
```

Comment: mmh i get an error here: if(!is_null($descriptionArr) { and says:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: ok i fixed some little error and it works well thank you! You forgot a ) in this line: if(!is_null($descriptionArr) <-- here. And then i write description LIKE '%{$search}%' instead description LIKE %{$search}%  and it works.

Comment: The answer should reflect the OP's changes in comments, should the comment be deleted.